I need a way to upload a newly generated image in a the FLET app
Goal: be able to upload an image in the flet app, show the image in-app along with the predictions, and then show the annotated image with bounding boxes based on the prediction.
I've trained the dataset via YOLOv5
Images related to the problem:
flet app
the new folder created after the button is clicked
Problem: once I click on the "show annotated image" button, instead of doing what it says it does in-app, it creates a new folder for the annotated image in the same path
Code:
import flet as ft
import torch
from pathlib import Path
import time

# Path to your YOLOv5 model weights
model_path = Path(r"D:\Desktop\PHCOINS_G8_DATA\yolov5\runs\train\exp3\weights\best.pt")

# Load the YOLOv5 model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path=model_path, force_reload=True)

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "YOLOv5 Image Prediction"
    page.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.DARK

    # Placeholder for the uploaded image and prediction result
    image_placeholder = ft.Image(width=400, height=400)
    prediction_result = ft.Text("Predictions: ", width=300)
    annotated_image_placeholder = ft.Image(width=400, height=400)

    uploaded_image_path = None

    def upload_image(e: ft.FilePickerResultEvent):
        if e.files:
            nonlocal uploaded_image_path
            uploaded_image_path = e.files[0].path
            image_placeholder.src = uploaded_image_path
            image_placeholder.update()
            predict_image(uploaded_image_path)

    def predict_image(file_path):
        # Perform inference
        results = model(file_path)
        # Extract predictions
        predictions = results.pandas().xyxy[0]
        prediction_text = "Predictions:\n"
        for _, row in predictions.iterrows():
            prediction_text += f"{row['name']}: {row['confidence']:.2f}\n"
        prediction_result.value = prediction_text
        prediction_result.update()

        # Save annotated image
        annotated_save_dir = Path("D:/Desktop/PHCOINS_G8_DATA/annotated")
        annotated_save_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        annotated_image_path = annotated_save_dir / (Path(file_path).stem + ".jpg")
        results.save(save_dir=str(annotated_save_dir))

    def show_annotated_image(e):
        if uploaded_image_path:
            predict_image(uploaded_image_path)
            time.sleep(1)  # Ensure the image is saved before trying to load it

            # Get the latest annotated image
            annotated_save_dir = Path("D:/Desktop/PHCOINS_G8_DATA/annotated")
            latest_annotated_image = max(annotated_save_dir.glob("*.jpg"), key=lambda p: p.stat().st_mtime)
            
            annotated_image_placeholder.src = str(latest_annotated_image)
            annotated_image_placeholder.update()

    def reset_image(e):
        global uploaded_image_path
        uploaded_image_path = None
        image_placeholder.src = ""
        image_placeholder.update()
        prediction_result.value = "Predictions: "
        prediction_result.update()
        annotated_image_placeholder.src = ""
        annotated_image_placeholder.update()

    file_picker = ft.FilePicker(on_result=upload_image)
    page.overlay.append(file_picker)
    
    upload_button = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Upload Image", on_click=lambda _: file_picker.pick_files(allow_multiple=False))
    show_annotated_button = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Show Annotated Image", on_click=show_annotated_image)
    reset_button = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Reset", on_click=reset_image)

    page.add(
        ft.Column(
            [
                ft.Row([upload_button, reset_button], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER),
                ft.Row(
                    [
                        ft.Column(
                            [
                                image_placeholder,
                                show_annotated_button,
                            ],
                            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                            horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
                        ),
                        ft.Column(
                            [
                                annotated_image_placeholder,
                            ],
                            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                            horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
                        ),
                        prediction_result
                    ],
                    alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                    vertical_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.START
                )
            ],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
            horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
        )
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)

